# Powerpoint VBA to highlight image on mouse click

Tags: vba, onclick, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint 2013 presentation. On the first slide I have 15 images. A mouse click on the image changes a variable in the VBA macro, but it does not look like the image has been clicked on by the user so it might be confusing if they clicked it or not.

I want to alter that image that they clicked to show it was clicked. I don't care if its a highlight or shadow or the image changes.

```
Sub Resize()
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        .Height = 2.78 * 72
        .Width = 4.17 * 72
        .Left = 0.78 * 72
        .Top = 1.25 * 72
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With
End Sub

Sub DefButton1Clicked()
    Element1 = 1
    Resize
End Sub
```

this does not work.

Ok I have figured this out here is what I did:

```
Sub DefButton1Clicked(oSH As Shape)
Element1 = 1
MsgBox oSH.Name
oSH.Shadow.Type = msoShadow17
oSH.Shadow.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 128)
oSH.Shadow.OffsetX = 3
oSH.Shadow.OffsetY = 2
End Sub
```

I was also able to reset the other button once the one button was clicked by doing this:

```
Dim oImg1 As Shape
Set oImg1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Item("Picture 7")
oImg1.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
Dim oImg2 As Shape
Set oImg2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Item("Picture 8")
oImg2.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
```

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki. Answer is in the question. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.

Ok I have figured this out here is what I did:

```
Sub DefButton1Clicked(oSH As Shape)
Element1 = 1
MsgBox oSH.Name
oSH.Shadow.Type = msoShadow17
oSH.Shadow.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 128)
oSH.Shadow.OffsetX = 3
oSH.Shadow.OffsetY = 2
End Sub
```

I was also able to reset the other button once the one button was clicked by doing this:

```
Dim oImg1 As Shape
Set oImg1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Item("Picture 7")
oImg1.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
Dim oImg2 As Shape
Set oImg2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Item("Picture 8")
oImg2.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
```